# How do you make a div go above another div when the page reaches a specific width?

Tags: html, css

I successfully created two separate divs: one that `floats left` and one that `floats right`. Both of them are in the same section.

**I would like the div to appear above the second div when the page is resized to about 600px.**

**Here is the code**

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

#left {
  float: left;
}

#me {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 50%;
}

#right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<section class="wrapper">

  <div id="left">
    <img id="me" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/4/47/Spongebob-squarepants.svg/1200px-Spongebob-squarepants.svg.png">
  </div>

  <div id="right">
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: Google "media queries"

Comment: Or any given framework like Bootstrap, Foundation, Materialize, etc. Heck, flexbox and the CSS grid can even do this *without* media queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `media query` to get this layout. You just have to add `flex-flow: row wrap;` in `media query` for .`wrapper`.

> When you are using `flex` property for an `element`, you don't have to
>   give `float` property for it's child element.

**Here is the working *Sinppet***

```css
.wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#me {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 50%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 576px) {
  .wrapper {
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;  
    -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="wrapper">

  <div id="left">
    <img id="me" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/4/47/Spongebob-squarepants.svg/1200px-Spongebob-squarepants.svg.png">
  </div>

  <div id="right">
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have already set display: flex; to your .wrapper so floating the nested elements is redundant. You can use media queries to achieve what you're after.

```css
.wrapper {
display: flex;
}

#me {
width:auto;
height:auto;
max-width:50%;
}


@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
  .wrapper {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="wrapper">

  <div id="left">
    <img id="me" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/4/47/Spongebob-squarepants.svg/1200px-Spongebob-squarepants.svg.png">
  </div>

  <div id="right">
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>

</section>
```